# Trouble whith outgoing mailserver on Odoo

Tags: python, json, odoo

I'm having trouble with my Odoo installation on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to fetch the mail on Odoo looks everything well, but when I tail the log file then I can find a lot of errors:

```
    015-01-20 20:41:42,192 2597 ERROR COMPANYNAME openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 524, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 545, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 301, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 298, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 761, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 394, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 953, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 941, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py", line 215, in test_smtp_connection
    raise osv.except_osv(_("Connection Test Succeeded!"), _("Everything seems properly set up!"))
except_orm: (u'Verbindungstest erfolgreich!', u'Alles scheint richtig konfiguriert zu sein.')
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

This is misleading.  The Odoo developers 'cheated' by using an exception to show you an information window.

```
def test_smtp_connection(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for smtp_server in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        smtp = False
        try:
            smtp = self.connect(smtp_server.smtp_host, smtp_server.smtp_port, user=smtp_server.smtp_user,
                                password=smtp_server.smtp_pass, encryption=smtp_server.smtp_encryption,
                                smtp_debug=smtp_server.smtp_debug)
        except Exception, e:
            raise osv.except_osv(_("Connection Test Failed!"), _("Here is what we got instead:\n %s") % tools.ustr(e))
        finally:
            try:
                if smtp: smtp.quit()
            except Exception:
                # ignored, just a consequence of the previous exception
                pass
    raise osv.except_osv(_("Connection Test Succeeded!"), _("Everything seems properly set up!"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So, what should I do now?

Comment: Well that error isn't really an error so you can just ignore that error text in the logs.  Is your outgoing mail actually working?

Comment: WI, no it isn't working. The incoming mail works well. Would the reinstall of the outgoing module help? Is that posible?

Comment: No, the emailing bit is part of the base. Are you sure that it is actually the outgoing server that is the issue?  It could be that an email isn't being triggered.  I'm not sure what you're doing but maybe your user preferences (top right) need to have 'Receive Messages by Email' set to 'All Messages'

Comment: If you want some info on sending emails with a server action, you can check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908437/how-to-create-program-for-sending-mail-automatically-from-openerp-using-python/25448413#25448413) at the bottom